# getElementsByTagName(...).0.parentNode' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, internet-explorer-8, bytecode

I'm using Google Chart for my application and I have to convert the **generated chart to image byte code**. I've done this in Firefox and Chrome but **IE8 is not responding to get the svg element**, So now I can't to get the byte code from the given div element. My script to convert div element to byte code is given below

```
function getElement() {
    for (var i = 0; i < divelement.length; i++) {
        toImg(document.getElementById(divelement[i]), i, medicalconditionid[i]);
    }
}

function toImg(chartContainer, i, id) {
    var field = document.createElement("input");
    field.type = "hidden";
    field.id = "img_code" + i;
    field.name = "imgcode";
    document.getElementById("dynamicText").appendChild(field);
    document.getElementById('img_code' + i).value = id + "_" + getImgData(chartContainer);
    i++;
}

function getImgData(chartContainer) {

    var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
    var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
    var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
    var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);
    canvas.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'position: absolute; ' +
        'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
        'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
    doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvg(canvas, svg);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
    return imgData;
}
```

I'm getting a `Line: 85
Error: 'getElementsByTagName(...).0.parentNode' is null or not an object` error in IE8.

Comment: Check that `chartContainer` is what you'd expect before you try to get any elements inside it.  Just do `console.log(chartContainer)` to see what it is.

Comment: im getting the expected element only, but in firefox and crome svg element is present and in IE8 IFrame element is present. Thats the problem

Comment: Great - so you can take it from there then :)

Comment: i have to take the div elements and then convert to byte code as the code above and the generated byte code will be taken in class file and change to image and download. this is my process

Comment: But you've already said there's no svg element in IE8 - you have an iframe instead.  Can you link the page?  With something so specific it would help to have a page to view.

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 does not support `canvas` or `SVG`. I don't think this is going to work in that browser. Support for both of them was added in IE9.

Comment: is there any alternative way to convert google chart to byte code from  IE8.

Comment: i can view the chart in IE8 but cant to convert to byte code @OllyHodgson

Comment: @Hariprasath No, I don't think IE8 can do this. You might be able to do it on the server, but that's a another question entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in IE8 there is **no support for svg or canvas element**, so the javascript charting libraries like **google charts, D3 and jqplot convert the charts to vml format** so we cant to get the byte code as like above code. In my application google chart can produce image format charts that is deprecated but i used this image chart and send the image url to action class and convert the url to image. Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard) link for google image charts