# how to convert div element into image

Tags: java, javascript, html, google-visualization

im using google charts for my application. i've to convert the **chart into png image** and store that image file in local. for that i've used like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542549/how-to-convert-div-element-to-byte-code) but i cant to convert the chart to image in IE8, i should code for IE8 also. is there any other way to convert the chart to png. Is it good way to convert the chart in server side. if so please suggest me to get png image file from the server side in java struts2 application. Thank you in advance.

Comment: HTML5 <canvas> tag may helps you

Comment: that canvas tag is not working in IE8

Comment: There's [VML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee384217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IEs<9, maybe you can use it?

Comment: could you have any example code to convert the chart to **image/png;base64** using VML

Comment: Unfortenately I can't. I have used VML to show 3D CAD models in IE, but it was ten years ago. You could browse the documentation, if you'd find something usefull...

Comment: look into [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), it may help.

Comment: is there any options in server side. html2canvas element doesn't support in IE8.

Comment: I have not tried this, but you might have some luck with the proposed solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11234583/613559

Comment: for the above problem i found the solution please refer [this][1] link


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542549/how-to-convert-div-element-to-byte-code/19681698#19681698

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are also using a `<canvas>`-element (as in the post you referenced), you can try using [ExplorerCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/), which brings canvas-functionality to old Internet Explorer version (make sure to use conditional tags for loading).

Another possibility, as Teemu mentioned, is using VML. I haven't found any script to convert canvas to VML, but I did manage to find this: [svg2vml](http://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/). I guess there should also be variants of this that work with canvas.

Comment: in ie8 we cannot convert the chart to image and again to byte code using excanvas and vml is a huge process